# Ember ApplicationRoute cannot handle error events

Tags: error-handling, ember.js

I cannot get my ApplicationRoute to handle errors. 401 or 500 (From Login operation) response from server did not fire the error event in my ApplicationRoute. Please Help!
I can see the 401 or 500 error in the console log.

```
FullCircle.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  events: 
    error: (reason, transition) ->
      alert reason

  actions: 
    logout: ->
      this.controllerFor('application').logged_out()
      delete localStorage.authToken
      this.transitionTo 'login'

FullCircle.LoginRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  actions: 
    login: ->
      self = this
      loginController = @controllerFor 'login'
      data = loginController.getProperties("username", "password")
       # this would normally be done asynchronously

      $.post("/login", data).then (response) ->
        alert response.message
        if response.user
          localStorage.authToken = response.token

          applicationController = self.controllerFor 'application'
          transition = applicationController.get 'savedTransition'

          # set isLoggedIn so the UI shows the logout button
          applicationController.logged_in()

          # if the user was going somewhere, send them along, otherwise
          # default to `/posts`
          if transition
            transition.retry()
          else
            self.transitionTo '/documents'
```

Answer (score 0):

As of ember 1.0, the events hash was renamed to actions. A route's error handler should be in the actions hash. So:

```
FullCircle.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  actions: 
    error: (reason, transition) ->
      alert reason
    logout: ->
      ...
```

Comment: Thank for your response. But I tried that with no luck. Do I need in before_model or model in order to capture the error event?

Comment: Yes, looking at your login action it is calling `$.post("/login", data)` but passing only a success fx. The error event will only be called if one of the model hooks (like before_model or model) throws an error or returns a promise that does not resolve. Have a look at the embercasts.com episodes on client-side authentication...